# jQuery caching data in <select> elements SLOW

Tags: jquery, html, caching, html-select

I'm trying to create a filter box for a large set of select options in a scrolling list.

I have to cache the data so that it can re-load upon a backspace. This works for smaller datasets,but it is taking WAY too long when I have about ~100,000 `option` items in the `<select>` list.

How else can I get my code to work?

```
var showOnlyOptionsSimilarToText = function (selectionEl, str) {
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    // cache the jQuery object of the <select> element
    var $el = $(selectionEl);

    if (!$el.data("options")) {
        // cache all the options inside the <select> element for easy recovery
        $el.data("options", $el.find("option"));  <------- TOO SLOW
    }



    var newOptions = $el.data("options").filter(function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    text = text.toLowerCase();

    return this.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(str) != -1

    });

    $el.empty().append(newOptions);
};

$("#search").on("keyup", function () {

    var userInput = $("#search").val();
    showOnlyOptionsSimilarToText($("#trends"), userInput);
});
```

Comment: `$el.children()` or `$el[0].childNodes` or even `$el[0].options` might be faster. Since it's a select element, you know for a fact that all of it's children are options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Jquery ui autocomplete, and grab the data via AJAX.  You're going to max out the browser trying to do things as you are.  IE will cause you the most pain.  Better to leave things server side if you can.

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: I can't do things via autocomplete. I need to return multiple matches, not just one.

Comment: Mark, i'm trying to help.  At least VISIT THE JQUERY UI page and see what it does -- which includes showing multiple matches, right out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I checked out the documentation and though it's not what I'm looking for, I'll be more thoughtful in my replies in the future ;)